# Operator is Fredholm if it is the sum of an Invertible and a Compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I just read from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462753/on-fredholm-operator) that if an operator $T$ from and to a Banach space can be written as a sum of a compact operator and an invertible operator then it is Fredholm.

I would like to prove this but I don't get it. Can someone help me?

Comment: First, we can reduce it to the case where the invertible operator is the identity on the Banach space $X$. Then it's easy to see that $\ker (I + K)$ is finite-dimensional for compact $K$. The harder thing is showing that $I + K$ has closed range and finite codimension. Rudin proves it in theorem 4.25. The Schwartz lemma (not to be confused with the Schwarz lemma) proves the latter fact in a more general setting. What can you build on?

Comment: I am sorry @DanielFischer I have no Idea...